# In bash how can I get the complete command line including pipes in one variable?

Tags: linux, bash

In bash how can I get the complete command line including pipes in one variable?

I want to include the command line in error messages. For example, I have a program that takes a list of file paths as input. It can read the paths from a file:

```
sh fileChecker.sh file-contining-paths.txt &
```

But it can also read from standard input

```
grep 'zip\|tar\|exe' file-containing-paths.txt | sh fileChecker.sh &
```

When there is an error message I would like to include the file name or the grep command.

```
Line 123 in file-contining-paths.txt javax.imageio.IIOException: ./attachments/foo.zip
```

or this, for the second example

```
Line 105 in grep 'zip\|tar\|exe' file-containing-paths.txt javax.imageio.IIOException: ./attachments/foo.zip
```

I tried using ps but the forked process doing the grep has already finished when I check.

I can use history in the interactive shell, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101673/get-last-bash-command-including-pipes) but it won't work in a script. The same applies to jobs and fc.

some related posts

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/531625/is-it-possible-to-access-the-complete-command-line-including-pipes-in-a-bash-scr

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163145/how-to-get-whole-command-line-from-a-process

[Get last bash command including pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101673/get-last-bash-command-including-pipes)

Comment: You can't. If you have a pipe, it means that you have at least two processes. Both sides of a pipe are only seen by the shell, when parsing the command line, but since the shell does not store this anywhere, you can't retrieve it.

Comment: Since you are spawning the processes to the background, jobs -l should give you the information you require.

Comment: @RamanSailopal : Please use backticks around `jobs -l`. First I thought you wrote something about `background, jobs` and started a new sentence with `I should give you ..`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `jobs -l`, like history, produce no output in my test script.

Comment: I agree with @user1934428. This is not possible.  
But I have found a way to work round the problem.  
  
Instead of running the pipe on the command line, it can be passed to the script as a command.  
sh fileChecker.sh "find -type f | grep 'zip\|tag\|exe'" &

The command is executed inside fileChecker.sh and piped to the consumer, CheckFiles along with the command, which is now available for error messages.

fileChecker.sh looks like this

`#!/bin/bash
bash -c "$@ | java gordon.checker.Checkfiles \"$@\""`